# disable sequence - rails with existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

All,

Here is my situation. I am using couple of tables (users, contacts) from existing database for my new application. I can NOT alter these table. contacts has a sequence for primary key and is inserted by using a trigger on both tables when we create a new user.

on my model class I set the primary key (using set_primary_key) of the contact table. When I try to create a new user. Rails is looking for a sequence and I get the following error.

ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Is there a way to disable the sequence?.

Thanks,
Aanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your contacts class, try adding:

```
class Contacts ...

  alias yourprimarykey id
  alias yourprimarykey= id=

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just  add a sequence and set it in class.
For example, add a  sequence named `'EXAMPLE_SEQ'` to your class:

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'yourclass'
  self.primary_key = 'your_primary_key'
  self.sequence_name = 'EXAMPLE_SEQ'
end
```

Comment: Here's a link to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sequence_name-3D) you could add.